# Find the x value based on a regression inverse function in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, inverse, nonlinear-functions

I was seeking for solutions to inverse functions in R. The `uniroot()` indicates a possible to do this, however I don't know how.
My problem is quite simple, I guess. I have a nonlinear regression as trigonometric function:

`function(d,x) d*sqrt(-0.9298239*(x-1)+0.0351246*sin(2.0737115*pi*x)+0.0037540*(1/tan(pi*x/2)))`

I need to find the x value based on y value. How can I do that?

Edit: If I plot the curve using the expression `(f(x)-y)` I have something like the image below. Now, how could I extract the value that minimizes in zero?

[minimization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZhVI.png)

Comment: Did you try at all to use `uniroot`? Where did you get stuck exactly? Keep in mind that unitroot finds where a function is equal to zero. But you can find where it equals any value `y` by minimizing the different between f(x) and y, or `(f(x)-y)^2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried the `uniroot` but the result is weird. I don't know what exactly the uniroot do and if its the function that I'm looking for. I need to find the x value given observed y value. So, if I try this `(f(x)-y)^2` could I find the root? And if I try this `(f(x)-y)` the absolute value?

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works when I plot a curve of the function with the expression `(f(x)-y)`. Now, how could I extract the value that minimizes? The uniroot function prints a error mensage like this: `f () values ​​at the ends have no opposite signs` @MrFlick

Comment: @MrFlick any suggestions?